# Can you put Ardupilot on any flight controller?

Tags: drone

Some FC's say that they support cleanflight and have no mention of Ardupilot. Is this just because its what's recommended or because it's all that works?

Comment: Probably the Ardupilot is based on Atmel MCU, like Arduino. The newest flight controller are based on STM32F4 and STM32F7.

Comment: This is a *usage* question which should be asked on the support forum for the *software* in question, it is not an *electronic design* question fitting here.  If you were personally trying to *port* the software and had a very specific question about a difficulty in your attempt to match a particular capability with a different MCU's peripherals, that might be on topic if well supported with the details of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are pre-built binaries for many flight controllers.

http://firmware.ardupilot.org/ lists out the different ardupilot builds (arducopter, arduplane, etc.) and by clicking on them , you can see the different versions, then the different builds per version.

[This document](http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/pre-built-binaries.html) goes into more detail on the file structure they use for pre-built binaries.